# Unable to create object of child class - TypeError: HomePage_1.HomePage is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, protractor, mocha.js

I am using typescript with Protractor and mocha. Basically trying to run a test that will go through multiple pages. I am trying to use POM but unable to instantiate objects when I use inheritance.

Getting below error when I try to create new object:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: HomePage_1.HomePage is not a constructor

I can instantiate an object of a class which does not extend from any other class though (nav object below has no issues). I tried various suggestions from similar questions here but none of them seems to work.

This is my test class: e2e.ts

```
import { browser } from 'protractor';
import { Navigation } from './core/Navigation';
import { HomePage } from './page-objects/HomePage';

var nav = new Navigation(); // <-- SUCCESS NO PROBLEMS
var hmPg = new HomePage(); // <-- FAILS HERE
 describe('Add product to cart',async function() {
        it("start from homepage", async function() {
             nav.navigate("index");
        });

        it("Perform search", async function() {
              hmPg.search("monopoly board game");
        });

//some more tests here till adding the product to cart
});
```

HomePage class: HomePage.ts

```
import {browser, element, protractor} from 'protractor';
import { BasePageObject } from './BasePageObject';

export class HomePage extends BasePageObject{

    private EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    private map;

    constructor(){
        super();
        super.loadMap(process.cwd()+"\\page-objects\\homePage.json");
    }

    public search(product:string){
       //some stuff here
    }

    //some more methods here.
}
```

this is my BasePageObject.ts class:

```
//some imports here
export class BasePageObject{

    //to store parsed json
    public mapData;
    public mapPath:string;
    public contentData;
    public contentPath:string;

    constructor(){
        //nothing to do here. Just setting the logger.
        log = factory.getLogger("BasePageObject");
    }
  //some other methods here
}
```

here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "paths": { "*": ["types/*"] },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "mapRoot": "./dist/out-tsc/",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
    ]
  }
}
```

also this is the generated js file after running tsc for my test class:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var protractor_1 = require("protractor");
var Navigation_1 = require("./core/Navigation");
var HomePage_1 = require("./page-objects/HomePage");

var nav = new Navigation_1.Navigation();
var hmPg = new HomePage_1.HomePage(); <--- FAILS HERE
describe('Add product to cart', function () {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
        return __generator(this, function (_a) {
            this.timeout(90000);
            it("start from homepage", function () {
                return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
....
...
..
.
```

here is my dependencies from package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.7",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.17",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "graphviz": "0.0.9",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "npm-failsafe": "^0.4.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "protractor-screenshot-utils": "^1.0.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "serenity-cli": "^0.11.3",
    "serenity-js": "^1.10.13",
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.18.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.2",
    "typescript-logging": "^0.6.3",
    "yargs": "^13.2.4"
}
```

It should be pretty straight forward, `var obj = new Class()` right? That doesn't work.

Comment: @Yevhen not sure if i got your question right. I did not use any specific code to export classes since they have export statement in beginning. on the other hand JS generated by tsc using es6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code included in the question is not enough to see what the problem is. But based on whatever can be gathered, you are using async/await with protractor promise manager set to false.

If that is the case then it is expected that you have to handle the asynchrony by yourself wherever that is in the i.e. constructor, methods etc.

That error simply means that somewhere you have code that is async in nature and the resulting Promise is not handled. I would suggest look for all the code that gets executed as part of `new HomePage()`.

Also, just quickly skim through the code to identify any such cases of unhandled promises.

Hope that helps...